# change the webview fontsize with seek bar

Tags: android, webview

`TextView` font changes easily with seekbar's *onProgressChanged()* event.. but i'm unable to do the same with `WebView`.

But after refresh/reload font size changes.

Can't it be done like `TextView`?

Answer (score 0):

you will have to access the webview settings object and change the textvalue from there.

**For devices before API 13 / ICS** :

you can use enums to set the text size value, take a look here [TextSize](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.TextSize.html)
the code would look like this

```
webView.getSettings().setTextSize(TextSize.LARGE);
```

For **ICS and later** you can set text size by:

```
webView.setTextZoom(200); // % of text size .
```

for more about webview settings take a look here : [WebSettings](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html)

Comment: thatsnot what i was asking. But thank you so much for taking your time to answer. I fixed my problem by replacing webView.getSettings().setDefaultFixedFontSize(seekvalue); to webView.getSettings().setDefaultFontSize(seekvalue);